# Shiny: updateTextInput not working with an actionButton

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm having a problem and can't really find the error. This is part of a much larger app and I need help with the following, when pressing the action button, all the boxes change to the hardcoded value.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

inputs_caja <- paste("caja", seq(1, 18, 1))
vector_cantidad_proyeccion <- rep(180, 18)

caja_columnas <- list()

hoy <- if_else(day(today()) %in% c(29, 30, 31), today() - 3, today())

seq_proyeccion <- str_replace(format(seq.Date(hoy + months(1, abbreviate = FALSE), hoy + years(1) + months(6, abbreviate = FALSE), by = "month"),
                                     "%Y-%m"), "-", "\n  -")

for (i in 1:length(inputs_caja)) {
  caja_columnas[[i]] <- column(1,
                               textInput(
                                 inputId = inputs_caja[i],
                                 label = seq_proyeccion[i],
                                 value = vector_cantidad_proyeccion[i],
                                 width = "100%"
                               )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,
           actionButton("cambiar_valores", "Change values")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(caja_columnas[1:9]),
  fluidRow(caja_columnas[10:18])
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$cambiar_valores, {
    for (i in 1:length(inputs_caja)) {
      updateTextInput(
        session = session,
        inputId = inputs_caja[i],
        value = "123"
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For some reason the button is not working, I don't really find any problem in the code.

Any clue as to what the problem could be would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the spaces from your `InputId`s, i.e. use `"caja1"` instead of `"caja 1"`. See e.g. https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-ui.html#common-structure